# How to select and display both category and subcategory from hierarchical list with OnTapGesture

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have  issue with the code to get both category and subCategory name from hierarchical list when it selected via onTapGesture.
For example when I select housing category which is without any subcategory, The onTapGesture is correctly displaying the category name and its icon in the Selected Category Section. However when I select the category list with the subCategory, the onTapGesture is only selecting subCategory item name from the list .

However I am looking for the updated code so whenever I select the subCategory , it will also select the category name and icon for this particular subCategory.

For example if I select the Housing category I want  to display following Items only in the the Selected  Category Section:

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: item.icon) // this will be housing icon
    Text(item.name)              // this will be housing name 
}
```

And if I select the the telephone subcategory from the Bills Category , I want  to display the following items only in the Selected Category Section.

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: item.icon) // this will be bills icon
    Text(item.name)              // this will be bills category name
    Text(item.subCategoryName)   // this will be Telephone SubCategory name which I have the issue with the code to get subCategory name. 
}
```

Following is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct Category: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var name: String
    let icon: String
    var subCategory: [Category]? = nil
    let id = UUID()

    static func preview() -> [Category] {
        [Category(name: "Bills",
                  icon: "lightbulb",
                  subCategory: [Category(name: "Electricity",
                                      icon: "lightbulb"),
                             Category(name: "Telephone",
                                     icon: "lightbulb")]),
         Category(name: "Transport",
                 icon: "car",
                subCategory: [Category(name: "Taxi",
                                    icon: "car")]),
         Category(name: "Housing", icon: "house")]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var items = Category.preview()
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var icon: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List(items, children: \.subCategory) { item in
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: item.icon)
                            Text(item.name)

                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            icon = item.icon
                            name = item.name
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Category List")
                }
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: icon) // Category icon
                        Text(name) // Category Name
                 //  Code to display subCategory name here for the selected 
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Selected Category")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: No issues here. I even changed the icons so every entry had a different one to make sure things were updating. Xcode 14.3.1, iOS 16.4. You may want to make a `@State` variable called selectedItem, and the use that as the selection, that way you would only have to pass 1 object, not two, if you were passing it to a different view.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb .  When I select subcategory of Telephone from bills category , I want the icon, bills and telephone to be updated in following section
Section {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                        Text(name)
                        //  Code to display icon Bills Telephone here

                    }

Comment: And it did update.

Comment: @Yrb. It’s only updating two objects, lightbulbs icon and telephone. I want all three objects to be updated. lightbulbs as icon , bills as name and telephone as subcategory. Thanks

Comment: It is updating ALL objects. If you are not seeing this in your own code, then you have not posted a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb. I am referring to Selected Category Section which is not getting updating with all three objects after being selected via onTapGesture! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edits, you want to show all subcategories for your main categories. You need to track the selected `Category` and not `Category's` parameters. Because `Category` has an infinite amount of levels, you need to create a view that displays `name` and `icon` and, if subcategories exist, calls itself recursively to handle each level.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = Category.preview()
    // You need to keep track of the Category, not the parameters on the Category.
    // This is nil until a Category is selected.
    @State private var selectedCategory: Category?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List(items, children: \.subCategory) { item in
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: item.icon)
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedCategory = item
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Category List")
                }
                
                Section {
                    // this unwraps the optional selectedCategory
                    if let selectedCategory {
                        CategoryView(selectedCategory: selectedCategory)
                    } else {
                        Text("Please select a category")
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Selected Category")
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryView: View {
    
    let selectedCategory: Category
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // this handles the top level.
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: selectedCategory.icon)
                Text(selectedCategory.name)
            }
            if let subCategories = selectedCategory.subCategory {
                // this handles the subcategories
                ForEach(subCategories) { subCategory in
                    CategoryView(selectedCategory: subCategory)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I created this for demonstration purposes only. In order to do what you want, you will need to change your underlying data structure. I would recommend implementing this with CoreData where you can more easily establish relationships between your objects. Otherwise, you are looking at a linked list. I updated your model to handle the UI, and changed the preview around to set it up as well, but hhis really is not a great data model and is for demonstration only.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var items = Category.preview()
    // You need to keep track of the Category, not the parameters on the Category.
    // This is nil until a Category is selected.
    @State private var selectedCategory: Category?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    List(items, children: \.subCategory) { item in
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: item.icon)
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedCategory = item
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Category List")
                }
                
                Section {
                    // this unwraps the optional selectedCategory
                    if let selectedCategory {
                        // THis will only go up one node
                        if let superCategory = selectedCategory.superCategory?.first {
                            CategoryView(selectedCategory: superCategory)
                        } else {
                            CategoryView(selectedCategory: selectedCategory)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text("Please select a category")
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Selected Category")
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryView: View {
    
    let selectedCategory: Category
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // this handles the top level.
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: selectedCategory.icon)
                Text(selectedCategory.name)
            }
            if let subCategories = selectedCategory.subCategory {
                // this handles the subcategories
                ForEach(subCategories) { subCategory in
                    CategoryView(selectedCategory: subCategory)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Category: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var name: String
    let icon: String
    private (set) var superCategory: [Category]?
    var subCategory: [Category]?
    let id = UUID()
    
    static func preview() -> [Category] {
        [Category(name: "Bills",
                  icon: "creditcard",
                  subCategory: [Category(name: "Electricity",
                                         icon: "lightbulb",
                                         superCategory: [Category(name: "Bills",
                                                                  icon: "creditcard",
                                                                  subCategory: [Category(name: "Electricity",
                                                                                         icon: "lightbulb")])]
                                         
                                        ),
                                Category(name: "Telephone",
                                         icon: "phone",
                                         superCategory: [Category(name: "Bills",
                                                                  icon: "creditcard",
                                                                  subCategory: [Category(name: "Telephone",
                                                                                         icon: "phone")])]
                                        )]),
         Category(name: "Transport",
                  icon: "airplane",
                  subCategory: [Category(name: "Taxi",
                                         icon: "car",
                                         superCategory: [Category(name: "Transport",
                                                                  icon: "airplane",
                                                                  subCategory: [Category(name: "Taxi",
                                                                                         icon: "car")])
                                         ]
                                         
                                        )]),
         Category(name: "Housing", icon: "house")]
    }
    
    mutating func setSupercategory(_ superCategory: Category) {
        // We don't want the actual Category as it would cause UI issues
        self.superCategory = [
            Category(name: superCategory.name,
                     icon: superCategory.icon,
                     superCategory: superCategory.superCategory,
                     subCategory: [self])]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yrb for your help. Yes, this is working fine.  For example I want bills and telephone objects to be displayed together in selected category section and not separately each! Thanks

Comment: That is not what you asked, but I will work on an answer. Please update your question to make it clear what you are asking so the answer makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb. Still when I select telephone subcategory, it is showing telephone subcategory in the selected category section instead of Bills Telephone.

Comment: Please edit your question to ask everything that you are looking fix.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope its clear now. @Yrb Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Yrb. The edited code has worked as I wanted. Your help and support is highly appreciated. I will also look into using Core Data to manage this kind of data structure.